# How do I do a SELECT COUNT statement only getting unique columns?

Tags: sql

I want to count how many results I get, but only where a certain column has unique values (not shared by any of the other results).

I tried:

```
select distinct user_token count(islibrarian) from customers where islibrarian = true;
```

But I get a syntax error what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The requirement is a bit unclear (at least to me). Could you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it? It would help clarify the question.

Comment: You have a missing comma between user_token and count(..);  also, please provide a proper sample input data and expected output showcasing your requirements

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyword DISTINCT  within the COUNT function:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_token) AS count_result FROM customers where islibrarian = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` with `having count(*)=1` clause :

```
select user_token, count(islibrarian) 
  from customers 
 where islibrarian = true
 group by user_token
 having count(*)=1;
```

P.S. It seems the mentioned *certain column* is **user_token**.